# What are the libguestfs basic packages

Tags: python, linux

I have created installer for Linux tool, this tool depends on **libguestfs**. 
The question is, what are the minimum required **libguestfs** packages I need to install in order for my tool to work?

Comment: That would largely depend on what parts of libguestfs you're using in your tool I suppose...?

Comment: Local mount functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the distro you are using and the version of libguestfs, but let's assume Fedora/RHEL/Debian and you're using libguestfs ≥ 1.18.

In that case for local mount functionality you will only need the basic library package, called `libguestfs` on Fedora-like or `libguestfs0` on Debian-like distros.  You may also want the fusermount tool which is part of FUSE.

If you're using guestfish, then you'll need the tools package.  On Fedora you can just depend on `/usr/bin/guestfish` which does the Right Thing.  On Debian it's in a package called `guestfish`.

If you're using libguestfs through bindings (eg. from Python) then you should also depend upon the bindings package, eg. `python-libguestfs` (Fedora) or `python-guestfs` (Debian).